# What interior design features involving math or logic are good ideas?

Tags: soft-question

What interior design features that involve mathematics or formal logic, or things related to mathematics or formal logic (things about the subjects count as well) are good ideas?

Comment: Maybe something with fractals, [Don Knuth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v678Em6qyzk) seems to like his

Comment: I recall reading about "random galleries".  That is, graphs with the property that any guest who drifts from vertex to vertex (i.e. room to room) randomly, using only the rule that a room once entered can never be reentered, will inevitably see all of the rooms.  A circular arrangement of rooms trivially has this property, but there are more interesting examples which, sadly, I forget how to construct.  I don't think it's difficult, however.

Comment: Are you acquainted with James Stewart's [Integral House](https://www.fastcodesign.com/3052267/the-house-that-calculus-built/)?

Comment: Google "penrose tiling wallpaper".

Comment: put a picture of every red thing in it

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, what do you mean?

Comment: if you paint a picture of every red thing in the universe, then the picture is red, and so should be in the picture...

Answer (score 5):

In 1975 I worked for about eight months for a place that made custom wood floors. When I realized I was returning to college, I gave the boss a number of sketches of floor designs. The one I know he used was this:

[image]
There is very little waste with this design, as the raw material comes as wood strips of constant width. As always, one may place strips of different color between the hexagons (which should all be the same type as far as number of pieces). There is skil involved: it turned out to work best to construct the hexagons in the shop on the very very thin plywood, (just one ply, we called it luan I think), as it would take forever for workers to place the strips at the job site. Completed hexagons, glued onto luan, could be cut as needed.

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/luan-wood-99466.html

Later I made a tabletop out of strips of walnut with this:

[image]
I did not do a good job.

Oh, when I got to Berkeley, I went to the public library, Art and Architecture room. I thought I would find the hexagon design in basketweaving, but that was not it. It has been used in mosaic design, very long ago.

Finally, because of the mystical significance of the number 42, I like this solid. 
Truncated rhombic triacontahedron, also called chamfered dodecahedron. The hexagons are not regular: they result from taking a rhombus with diagonal ratio the golden ratio, then truncating the two more pointy vertices to get a not quite regular hexagon.
[image]
There is a design place right around the corner from me, they seem to have lots of ceramic dodecahedra with glossy glazes. I made this out of Zometool pieces, maybe I will show them some day. However, they do not manufacture the decorative stuff they sell...

I put in lots of internal structure, an icosahedron with radii in the center, then... The pedestal is one of those cylindrical boxes of Quaker Oats.

[image]
[image]